# how to track a request in the webapplication. Is there any tool for this with which we can test a HTTP request

Tags: java, servlets, web

Recently came accross a question, If anybody has some idea pls share.
    How to track a HTTP request in browser, OR can say how to track a request in its lifecycle.
Is there any tool to test it.

Comment: Do you want to track the request header and content?

Answer (score 1):

To track the lifecycle of a HTTP request and response including all its headers and content data I can recommend the tool Fiddler2. It is basically a proxy that you plug between browser and your web server. It will track all data that flows out of your browser to the web server and back. It also allows you to do nice things like changing the request or response data to test various cases.

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

There is a great and straightforward tool for tracking HTTP requests. 
It works like a client for REST services.

This is the project in google code:

https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

And here is the .jar that you actually gonna use:

http://code.fosshub.com/WizToolsorg-RESTClient/downloads

It is not browser based as you asked, but it might help in some manner.

Hope I helped

Comment: how does rest client tracks a request, it is used to make the HTTP requests.